# How to return new line in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, newline, indentation

I am running following query -

```
SELECT 'SELECT * 
FROM LIFE'
```

I want the expected output as -

```
SELECT *
FROM LIFE
```

However, when I copy the result set in new window, it is

```
SELECT * FROM LIFE
```

As per the below answer, when I use following

```
SELECT 'SELECT * ' + char(13) + char(10) + 'FROM LIFE'
```

The output is still returned in one line with a wide space as follows -

```
SELECT *   FROM LIFE
```

Can I not get newline in the result-set? Sorry if I am missing something but I am not having strong SQL skills.

Comment: @canon: That's right, but the question is labelled [tag:sql-server-2008]

Comment: Try pasting it in Notepad first, than copy-paste it in SS2008. I know it's not the answer you need, but it excludes some fancy AI work from the SS2008 editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a carriage return ([ASCII 13](http://www.asciitable.com/)) and line feed ([ASCII 10](http://www.asciitable.com/)) like:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * ' + char(13) + char(10) + 'FROM LIFE'
```

Comment: Please see my edit in the question when I ran your query. It still returned result-set in one line.

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi: Did you try that in text mode? (menu `query -> results to -> results to text`, or keyboard `ctrl-T`)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this is working, but SSMS is replacing the carriage return when you copy it from the resultset.

I just ran the below excel-vba code against SQL Server 2008 R2, and the text printed into an excel sheet as it should. To test, open excel and paste the test() routine into a sheet module in the VBA editor (alt + f11), and then insert a new module (name it dbMngr) and then paste the dbMngr code below into that module.

EDIT: You'll also need to include a connection string constant at the top of the dbMngr module.

Integrated Security:

```
Private Const S_CON As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MyServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

SQL Server Auth:

```
Private Const S_CON As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MyServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDB;UID=MyUserName;PWD=MyPassword"
```

Test code:

```
Sub test()
Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = "SELECT 'LINE A' + Char(10) + Char(13) + 'LINE B'"

Me.Range("A1").Value = sSQL


dbMngr.PasteToRange sSQL, Me.Range("A4")

End Sub
```

dbMngr code:

```
Public Function GetRS(sSQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo errCatch:

With cn
    .ConnectionString = S_CON
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .Open
End With

With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Open sSQL
End With

Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
Set GetRS = rs

errCatch:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error in GetRS function"
    Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Stop
    Err.Clear
End If

If cn.State = adStateOpen Then
    cn.Close
End If

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub PasteToRange(sSQL As String, rngDest As Range)
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, x As Integer, orng As Range

rngDest.CurrentRegion.Value = ""

Set rs = GetRS(sSQL)

For x = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    rngDest.Offset(0, x).Value = rs.Fields(x).Name
Next x

rngDest.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
rngDest.CurrentRegion.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
rngDest.CurrentRegion.Font.Size = 8
rngDest.WrapText = False

If rs.State = adStateOpen Then
    rs.Close
End If

Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @TehJake for such a detailed answer, but I guess Andomar's answer worked for me. Much appreciate!